# JTable with ability to filter using swingx-1.6

Tags: java, jtable, swingx

I'm trying myself developing a desktop application with Java and Java Swing.
Currently I'm implementing a property table where can I handle different types of properties of an object. For that I created a custom table model.

However I got some problems adding a filter ability which shows only properties matching a given string.

I found a neat library called swingx which provides many functions I need, like filtering.

This tutorial (http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t18819.html) shows examples of how to implement it in JXTable but it won't work. Seems that swingx-1.6 kicked out the setFilter-method().

Any ideas?

```
Filter[] filterArray = { new PatternFilter("(.*1st.*)|(.*Final.*)", 0, 0) };
        FilterPipeline filters = new FilterPipeline(filterArray);
        table.setFilters(filters);
```

Comment: that's api in swingx 1.0 (for jdk 1.5). Current version (1.6.2) uses (enhanced, though) core sorting/filtering mechanism

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JTable supports filtering. See the section from the Swing tutorial on [Sorting and Filtering](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) for a working example.

Comment: Well, I found it out myself. Have had some problems with sorting my table and then deleting rows because it won't sort the model but only the view. So I thought with swingx it would be easier.  Conveniently the table provides functions like convertColumnIndexToModel(row) to get the right indexes. So I can use the RowSorter and add some filters.